# How make parse image from JSON

Tags: ios, json, parsing, uitableview

I have some project where i must paste image from JSON. I try to find any tutorial about this, try to see any video from this theme but nothing. So my problem have:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *playlist =[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"playlist_data"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in playlist) {

        NSString *name = [diction objectForKey:@"text1"];
        NSString *namesong = [diction objectForKey:@"text2"];
        NSString *images = [diction objectForKey:@"image"];
        NSLog(@"%@", images);        
        [array addObject:text1];
        [array2 addObject:text2];
    }
    [[self tableTrack]reloadData];
}
```

I added text 1 to cell also text 2 its work perfect but how to add image to to array 3(image in cell in my tableView)?
I tried also to added for image but its not work for me:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[appsdict objectForKey:@"image"]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
cell.imageView.image = imageLoad;
```

Please help with my problem or maybe give some tutorial with parse image from JSON, also youtube haven't perfect tutorial from JSON parse. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should keep them in the dictionary. Just keep the keys in an array. `keyArray = [ playlist allKeys ]`. Then when you want text1 for the third playlist, you can use `keyArray[2][@"text1"]`. Up to you, but I think this will make your code simpler.

Comment: What is the content of the `[diction objectForKey:@"image"]` ? Is it a URL or is it the Base64Encoded String of the Image?

Comment: Look i have NSDictionary with name dictin and in JSON have tag image. So text work but image not work.

Comment: You should note that you are not extracting an image from the JSON.  Rather, you are extracting a URL for the image.  The fact that it's an image URL is irrelevant to the JSON stuff, and, when you go to load the image off the net, the fact that the URL came from JSON is irrelevant.  It's much less confusing if you learn how to separate problems into pieces like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't keep multiple data source like `array1`, `array2`, `array3` etc. It is not good coding and will confuse while debugging/fixing issues. Instead maintain single array with information for displaying in individual cell of the table view.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in playlist) {
    // array is single data source
    [array addObject:diction];
}
```

Then while assigning data to the table view cell use,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text1 = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text1"];
    cell.text2 = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text2"];

    //For displaying image by lazy loading technique use SDWebImage.

   [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

   // If no place holder image, use this way
   // [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:nil];
}
```

Like I mentioned in comments for lazy loading images from the URLs in JSON response, use [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Usage is simple like I have shown above. Alternately you can implement lazy loading yourself by studying this sample code from Apple: [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! But for why UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"? I have only object for key "image" and in JSON under the tag image have url to pictures.

Comment: @user2470823 Usually, while image is still downloading, it is good practice to show a placeholder image. That is optional, you can choose not to show it, just set it `nil`.

Comment: Sorry! I have error class method +URLWithString:placeholderImage. What i can i do? sorry for this stupid question. And thanks big thanks for help

Comment: @user2470823 Your using different method. I suggested `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` for which you should `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"` from [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) code that you included in your project.

Comment: OKey i try this now and after will write. Thanks!

Comment: Its possible to make this without ARC..?

Comment: @user2470823 Yes `SDWebImage` is ARC compatible. It should not be a problem for non-ARC. Just mark the files as `-fobjc-arc`

Comment: I dont won't use ARC, but this SDWebImage work only with ARC or no?

Comment: Its possible to write me on Facebook?

Comment: @user2470823 Like I said above for non-ARC project you need to mark the `SDWebImage` project source files as `-fobjc-arc`. There is no non-ARC version of `SDWebImage` available.

Comment: Okey so i must write this "-fobjc-arc" in "Linking" section, locate the "Other Linker Flags" Yes?

Comment: @user2470823 No, check how to do this from here..http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/10/making-arc-and-non-arc-play-nice.html. You need to add a compiler flag, not linker flag.

Comment: aa Okey! So i must add -fobjc-arc to all files in Build Phases Yes?

Comment: @user2470823 Not all, just the source files for `SDWebImage` (which support ARC)

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
      +[UIImage(GIF) sd_animatedGIFWithData:] in UIImage+GIF.o
And i have 12 errors with this operation

Comment: Perfect i have only two errors Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKAnnotationView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MKAnnotationView_$_WebCache in MKAnnotationView+WebCache.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) What wrong i do?

Comment: HAh! Perfect project compile but i have one eror Class method '+URLWithString:placeholderImage:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')..What i must do ? Friend thanks for help!

Comment: Please write what i must do...i have this error and thats all

Comment: @user2470823 I'm not sure why you are getting that error. It does not concern with the code I've suggested.

Comment: I rename all files, i made all flags with no-arc after i wrote this in M file #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h". And i also have error with class not found, maybe SDWebImage have error or have another class name...

Comment: Maybe this code have any errors or [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]]; 
Where situated this placeholderImage? Maybe i can circumvent this placeholder? Only parse image from JSON and that's it.

Comment: @Genevios I have never faced such issues with `SDWebImage` before. May be as a workaround try using the block API of `SDWebImage` as mentioned here..https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-blocks

Comment: BUt this example also have this placeholderImage class which can not find. I have error only with this class

Comment: @Genevios You said you rename all files? Why and what does that mean? Is it possible to share your project, I can check once and let you know if I can figure out your issue. Actually now I am running out of suggestions.

Comment: A rename all files of SDWebImage folder.

Comment: Maybe i must import another file from SDWebImage?

Comment: @Genevios Why did you rename? any reason? afaik it is not required?

Comment: NO NO! I a only write flag for no arc i am not rename all files no i just wrote flags

Comment: @Genevios Sorry but I am not able to understand what is going wrong. Will be able to help if I can take a look at your project. Possible for you to share project?

Comment: Yes say please your account on Facebook or any?

Comment: @Genevios You can upload it to your dropbox account and share the link?

Comment: @Genevios Okay, let me check and see if I understand the issue.

Comment: @Genevios Solved, its my mistake, I am missing a `]` in that call after `URLWithString`. I have fixed it in the edit. Here is correct one `[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`. Try this one and let me know.

Comment: Add in my project this code and look, for why picture not show in tableviecell?

Comment: I have text all of my song and artists but picture not show..Where is trouble

Comment: @Genevios Because your response does not contain image URLs. Image urls print as `(null)` when you log them

Comment: I know i made NSLog and i can saw NULL. But its trouble in JSON or in my project?

Comment: @Genevios In the code just replace image URL with some harcoded URL and check if table view downloads the images. I am able to get your table view load image with harcoded URL.

Comment: So Work! Work! Work! Thanks i replace URL JSON from apple appstore and  picture show! Oh my God! Thanks man!!

Comment: You are developer only IOS or android also?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html and http://www.json.org/ you can't keep binary data in JSON (unless it is in base64).

It seems there's a problem with your `webdata` which is not a valid JSON. Did you check what is set under `@"image"` key in that dictionary while debugging? You can use `[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:webdata]` as well to see if your data is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
//prepare your method here..


-(void)hitimageurl{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:replacephotostring]];

    //set your image on main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



        if (_photosArray==nil) {
            _showImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noimg.png"];

        } else {
            [_showImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        }



    });
});
```